# Comparison of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n$ given $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n/b_n=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ and $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n$ be the power series representations of functions $f$ and $g$ around $0$ with $a_n>0$ and $b_n>0$ for all $n\geq 0$ (we assume that both power series converge on the whole $\mathbb{R}$). Suppose that
\begin{equation}\label{so}
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=0.
\end{equation}
What is the "strongest" conlusion that this condition can lead to? For example, we can say that $f(x)<g(x)$ for sufficiently large values of $x$. However, the latter also holds if we just assume that $a_n<b_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$, which is a much weaker assumption compared to what we have. I, therefore, think that in our case it may be reasonable to expect to have a stronger conclusion.

Comment: Why is $a_n<b_n\implies f(x)\le g(x)$? It's not true. Think of $x^2$ and $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$.

Comment: @Chrystomath: 1. Isn't it true that $x^2 < (x + 1)^2$ for sufficiently large values of $x$? $$ $$ 2. I don't think it actually satisfies $a_n < b_n$, don't you have $a_2 = b_2$ and $a_n = b_n = 0$ for all $n \ge 3$?

Comment: I believe we may assert that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$.

Comment: I don't think you can say much without making more assumptions because $b_n$ can be greater than $a_n$ by the tiniest of hairs like $b_n=\ln(\ln(n))a_n$, which when combined with say a small/finite radius of convergence means you can say very little about $g$ being greater than $f$.

Comment: Thanks! I think that there may be a stronger conclusion for large values of $x$. For example, as suggested above, it may be the case that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, we do have $f(x)/g(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty.$

Proof: Let $\epsilon>0.$ Then there exists $N$ such that $a_n/b_n < \epsilon$ for $n>N.$ Set $A_N(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_nx^n,$ $B_N(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{N}b_nx^n.$ Then$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{A_N(x) +\sum_{n>N}^{\infty}a_nx^n}{B_N(x) +\sum_{n>N}^{\infty}b_nx^n} <\frac{A_N(x) +\sum_{n>N}^{\infty}\epsilon b_nx^n}{B_N(x) +\sum_{n>N}^{\infty}b_nx^n}  =\frac{A_N(x)/(\sum_{n>N}^{\infty} b_nx^n) +\epsilon}{B_N(x)/(\sum_{n>N}^{\infty} b_nx^n) +1}.$$

As $x\to \infty,$ the last term $\to \dfrac{0+\epsilon}{0+1}=\epsilon.$ This shows $\limsup_{x\to \infty} f(x)/g(x) \le \epsilon.$ Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrarily small, this $\limsup$ equals $0,$ showing $f(x)/g(x)\to 0$ as desired.